# Intervention Image: Encoding format (png?v=73d79a89bded&a) is not supported

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am using `Laravel 5` [Embed](https://github.com/KaneCohen/embed) package to grab the meta data of external links. I then use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction) package to manipulate the default image of the link and save it on the disk.

All works well, until I try to submit a link to a `StackOverflow` question. Then I get this *error*:

> NotSupportedException in AbstractEncoder.php line 149:
>
> Encoding format (png?v=73d79a89bded&a) is not supported.
>
> in AbstractEncoder.php line 149
>
> at AbstractEncoder->process(object(Image), 'png?v=73d79a89bded&a', null) > in AbstractDriver.php line 77
>
> at AbstractDriver->encode(object(Image), 'png?v=73d79a89bded&a', null) in > Image.php line 119
>
> at Image->encode('png?v=73d79a89bded&a', null) in Image.php line 139
>
> at Image->save('C:\xampp\htdocs\r2\public/images/rwSuGpEB.png?v=73d79a89bded&a') in PostsController.php line 70

How do I deal with this in `Laravel` and Intervention package?

How do you remove `?v=73d79a89bded&a` from the `basename()`?

This is `create()` method in `PostsController`

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
    if (Input::has('link')) {
        $input['link'] = Input::get('link');
        $info = Embed::create($input['link']);

        if ($info->image == null) {
            $embed_data = ['text' => $info->description];
        } else if ($info->description == null) {
            $embed_data = ['text' => ''];
        } else {
            $extension = pathinfo($info->image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $newName = public_path() . '/images/' . str_random(8) . ".{$extension}";

            if (File::exists($newName)) {
                $imageToken = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 5);
                $newName = public_path() . '/images/' . str_random(8) . '-' . $imageToken . ".{$extension}";
            }
            // This is line 70
            $image = Image::make($info->image)->fit(70, 70)->save($newName);
            $embed_data = ['text' => $info->description, 'image' => basename($newName)];
        }

        Auth::user()->posts()->create(array_merge($request->all(), $embed_data));

        return redirect('/subreddit');
    }
    Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());

    return redirect('/subreddit');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a query string `?v=73d79a89bded&a` at the end if your image name.  That query string is being interpreted, incorrectly, as part of the image's file extension.

Remove that query string before further processing.

**UPDATE**

Assuming $extension holds the unwanted query string

```
$orig = pathinfo($info->image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extension = substr($orig, 0, strpos($orig, '?'));
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I already knew that. The question is, how can I remove it? I can use `basename()` to get the filename+extension.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from the original version of your question.  You could have significantly shortened it in that case.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for that. I updated my question after that. And thank you, that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accepting a URL, so you should use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) first:

```
$parts = parse_url($input['link']);
$extension = pathinfo($parts['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I'll also note that you should probably be using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` for paths.